# Assigning value to Html.DropdownList from a controller method via ViewBag

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a @Html.DropDownList on my view whose initial values are null. The values of the list must be populated based on the selected value from an other dropDownList. I have my two dropDownLists as below

```
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                @Html.DropDownList("City", null, new {@id="City", @class="form-control"})
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                @Html.DropDownList("Theatre", null, new {@id = "Theatre", @class = "form-control"})               
            </div>
```

Theatre must be populated based on the value selected in the dropDown list for city. As Theatre cannot be null, I initially set the ViewBag.Theatre to an empty list in my controller's action method. Once a city is selected, I am doing an ajax call from jQuery to call a different method in my controller to set the ViewBag.Theatre to my returned list.

But the contents of the Theatre dropDown are still empty. How do I refresh the contents of the dropDown after the ViewBag.Theatre value is changed?

Here is my jQuery to call the controller method

```
$("#City").change(function() {
if ($("#City").val() != 0) {
    var ty = $("#City").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: rootDir + "/AnalysisHistory/SetTheatres",
        data: {city: city },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function () {
            $(".form").show();
            $("#loading").hide();
            $("#analysisDetails").slideDown('slow');


    });
} else {
    $(".form").hide();
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On change for the dropdown list for the city, here is what I did to populate the theaters drop down:
  •I emptied the contents of the dropdown list for the theaters
  •As I am receiving the new list as a JSON, on Success, I am re-populating the list with new contents. Here is my code

```
success: function (datax) {
                var result = "";
                var listObj = $.parseJSON(datax);
                $(listObj).each(function (i, val) {
                    result += '<option value="' + val.Value + '">' + val.Text + '</option>';
                });
                $("#Theatre").html(result);
                $(".form").show();
                $("#loading").hide();
                $("#analysisDetails").slideDown('slow');
            }
```